# Consulta de dos tablas con condición

Tags: sql, sql-server

Quiero traer todas la materias de la *Tbl Materias* menos las materias que poseen el `estadomateria<>'aprobado'` y `estadomateria<>'regularizado'` que se encuentran en la *Tbl AlumnosMaterias*.

**Tabla Materias**:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Tabla AlumnosMaterias**:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

la respuesta puede ser un `Left Join` como el que te dejo aquí

```
SELECT M.* FROM Materias M
LEFT JOIN AlumnosMaterias AM ON AM.IdMateria = M.IdMateria 
WHERE AM.estadomateria <> 'aprobado' AND AM.estadomateria <> 'regularizado'
```

También puedes usar un `WHERE AM.estadomateria NOT IN ('aprobado','regularizado')` suponiendo que en un futuro tendrías que agregar mas restricciones a la consulta

Espero te sea de utilidad.

Comment: yo quiero mostrar el listado de materias menos las que tienen aprobado o regularizado en la tabla alumnomaterias. tu colsulta no me muestra las materias restantes que se encuentran en tbl materias.

Answer (score 1):

Voy a copiar el comentario que pusistes bajo la respuesta de @Ezequiel, porque creo que está mas claro que la descripción en la pregunta:

> Yo quiero mostrar el listado de `materias` menos las que tienen `aprobado` o `regularizado` en la tabla `alumnomaterias`.

Para excluir ciertas materias, puedes usar una claúsula `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select *
  from Materias m
 where not exists (select null
                     from AlumnosMaterias am
                    where am.idMateria = m.idMateria
                      and am.EstadoMateria in ('aprobado', 'regularizado'))
```

Comment: Al rato de comentar a Ezequiel lo resolvi porque segui leyendo sobre sql. Con una subconsulta muy parecida a la tuya. Aprovecho para consultar otra duda q m surgio recien..... quiero mostrar un campo mas llamado estadomateria de la tabla alumnosmaterias. Lo agregue a tu consulta pero me trae registros duplicados. Valoro mucho las respuestas dadas. Muchas gracias por el tiempo prestado.

Comment: Tendría que ver qué le agregastes a la consulta. Te sugiero de abrir una pregunta separada con tu nueva duda. Para una respuesta acertada y rápida, asegúrate de incluir una muestra de los datos, la consulta que has intentado, el rdsultado obtenido + el resultado deseado.

Comment: Muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 1):

Prueba con esta, debiera dar con el resultado:

```
 SELECT m.nombremateria
 FROM materias m
 INNER JOIN alumnosmaterias am ON am.idmateria=m.idmateria
 WHERE am.estadomateria NOT IN ('aprobado','regularizado')
```